# Delete an item from json file by key

Tags: php

I'm trying to delete an item from json file using id property match.

What is actually the unset i need?

```
Json data:
{"memory":[{"id":1,"pinned":false,"title":"my title","author":"me"}, 
 {"id":2,"pinned":false,"title":"my title","author":"me"}]}


$projectsArr = json_decode(file_get_contents("../db/memory.json"), true);

if(isset($_POST['subDelete'])) {
 $selectedIitemId = $_POST["subDelete"];
  foreach($projectsArr['memory'] as &$mydata) {
    if($mydata['id'] == $selectedIitemId) {
      // unset ?
      $save = json_encode($projectsArr,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
      file_put_contents('../db/memory.json', $save);
      header('LOCATION:approve.php');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what exactly do you want to delete (_an item_?), what doesn't work as expected?

Comment: Some sample data would be nice to work with to help you solve this.

Comment: Yes. Deleted an item by it's is. I tried various unst possibilities but none of them work. Should be easy i know...

Comment: Can you add `memory.json` to your post or a partial? In this way someone can test a possible solution without inventing that json structure not knowing how its really structured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code uses the index of the entry that matches and uses `unset()` from the array itself (`$projectsArr['memory']`).  Also as this then leaves an array with missing entries (which will cause it to save as an object) it uses `array_values()` to reset the keys before saving the data.

```
foreach($projectsArr['memory'] as $key => $mydata) {
    if($mydata['id'] == $selectedIitemId) {
        unset($projectsArr['memory'][$key]);
        $projectsArr['memory'] = array_values($projectsArr['memory']);
        $save = json_encode($projectsArr,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
        file_put_contents('../db/memory.json', $save);
        header('LOCATION:approve.php');
        exit;
    }
}
```